# maybe I'm confusing file path but cannot find clue

Tags: node.js, path, writefile

I'm trying to read a JSON file, edit the array, and save it to same file (overwrite).
nodejs reads the file, edit the array, overwrite it without any error.

But the file does NOT change. Maybe I'm confusing file path, but cannot find any clue. please help.

```
const bookFolder = require('../../bookFolder')
                   // ../../books/JSDG
                   // or, root/books/JSDG

const writeJSON = (body) => {
    let {file, en, ko} = body,
        chapterFile = `../../${bookFolder}/${file}.json`,
        chapter = require(`${chapterFile}`),
        mainFile = `../../${bookFolder}/sentences.json`,
        sentences = require(`${mainFile}`),
        object = {"en":en, "ko":ko};
    console.log(`chapterFile: ${chapterFile}`)
    // ../../books/JSDG/ch08.json (it points to correct file)

    let index = chapter.findIndex(o => o.en.toLowerCase() === en.toLowerCase());
    if (index === undefined) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(chapter, null, 2))
        return `Error: cannot find ${en} in ${chapterFile}`
    }

    sentences.push(object);
    fs.writeFileSync(mainFile, JSON.stringify(sentences, null, 2)); 

    chapter[index] = object;
    fs.writeFileSync(chapterFile, JSON.stringify(chapter, null, 2));
    return `ok finished writing`;
}
```

Everytime I try this, I see "ok finished writing", but the file never changes.
Folder structure looks like this:

```
root
    app.js
    ...
    books
        JSDG                ('bookFolder')
            ...
            ch08.json       ('chapterFile')
            sentences.json  ('mainFile')
    script
        editor
            server.js       (this file)
```

Comment: Sorry, your folder structure looks really confusing, In the paths, I saw you included `bookFolder`, but in the structure, you added to the right, it's confusing to imagine how the structure is, A screenshot of the structure or editing this will be really helpful to understand this.

Comment: And that `bookFolder` is required as `boolFolder` and never used in the code, it is something causing the issue?

Comment: @kgangadhar boolFolder is my typo. in the code, it is required as bookFolder correctly. sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Start with `console.log(process.cwd())`. Consider if you need `path.join(__dirname, pathname)`.

Comment: And the other issue I noticed is the `findIndex` result you are comparing to `undefined`, if it is not able to find it will return `-1`, it's better you check if it's `< 0` for throwing error.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks! node was saving files elsewhere. I tried log process.cwd and found that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was, I confused working directory with file's directory. Node was saving file relative to working directory, and I were looking relative to saved directory.